# Prove that a tournament with exactly one Hamlitonian path cannot have a length-three cycle

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path, directed-graphs

Define a *tournament* to be a directed graph such that for any two (distinct) vertices in the graph, there is exactly one edge between them.

I would like to show that a tournament with exactly one Hamiltonian path cannot have a length-three cycle. One approach I'm considering is a proof by contradiction; supposing to the contrary that a tournament with exactly one Hamiltonian path has a three-vertex cycle, then this Hamiltonian path cannot make use of every edge in this cycle. I'd like to show that there exists another Hamiltonian path that *does* make use of one of these unused edges, though I'm not sure that this is a viable approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call a tournament with $n$ players "qualifying" if there is a unique Hamiltonian path.

Claim all qualifying tournaments are triangle-free.

The claim holds vacuously if $n < 3$.

Proceed by induction on $n$.

Fix a positive integer $n \ge 3$, and suppose the claim holds for all qualifying tournaments with $n-1$ players.

Choose an arbitrary qualifying tournament $T$ with $n$ players, and label the players $P_1,...,P_n$ based on their order in the unique Hamiltonian path.

Thus, for all $i \in \{1,...n-1\}$, $P_i$ beats $P_{i+1}$.

Claim $P_i$ beats $P_n$, for all $i \ne n$.

Suppose otherwise.

Let $i$ be the least positive integer such that $P_n$ beats $P_i$.

By hypothesis, $i \ne n-1$.

If $i=1$, then
$$P_n,P_1,...,P_{n-1}$$
is a Hamiltonian path, contradicting uniqueness. Hence $i > 1$.

But then
$$P_1,...,P_{i-1},P_n,P_i,...,P_{n-1}$$
is a Hamiltonian path, again contradicting uniqueness.

Therefore $P_i$ beats $P_n$, for all $i \ne n$, as claimed.

But the $(n-1)$-player subtournament $T'$ without $P_n$ is also qualifying, since

- $T'$ has the Hamiltonian path $P_1,...,P_{n-1}$.$\\[2pt]$

  If $T'$ had more than one Hamiltonian path, then by appending $P_n$ to each such path, we would have more than one Hamiltonian path for $T$, contradicting uniqueness.

By the inductive hypothesis, $T'$ is triangle-free.

But then if $T$ has a triangle, it would have to include the vertex $P_n$, which is impossible since $P_n$ loses to each of the other players.

It follows that $T$ is triangle-free, which completes the induction, and hence completes the proof.

Moreover, since

- $T$ is triangle-free.$\\[2pt]$

  $P_i$ beats $P_{i+1}$ for all $i \in \{1,...n-1\}$.

it follows that
$$i < j \implies P_i\;\text{beats}\;P_j$$
hence $T$ is cycle-free, not just triangle-free.